# Расширенная форма текстового редактора сообщений

Tags: предложение, статус-отклонено, правки

Предлагаю ввести расширенную форму редактора ответов\вопросов.

Очень часто не хватает функционала текущего редактора сообщений.

Как образец (шаблон, макет) функционала хотел бы предложить редактор с форума cyberforum.ru:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Конкретно мне не хватает:

1) Выравнивания.

2) "Родной" подсветки синтаксиса топовых языков.

3) Табличного форматирования.

4) Тега "Спойлер".

Несколько примеров "родной" подсветки синтаксиса:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Зачем вам для того, чтобы задать вопрос целый Word? В Markdown из существенного не хватает только таблиц. А вся эта "игра со шрифтами" совершенно ни к чему.

Comment: Много кнопок не нужно.

Comment: Прочитайте внимательно заголовок, "Расширенная форма редактора". Кто хочет - тот ее и использует. Основной редактор не поменяется.

Comment: @Nofate, предложите свою версию редактора. В чем проблема?

Comment: @Nofate, вы так же забываете про "родную" подсветку синтаксиса топовых языков. Это очень удобно, когда в одном вопросе например пересекаются несколько языков или один язык и запрос к какой либо БД.

Comment: @Nofate, "Зачем вам для того, чтобы задать вопрос целый Word?" - это излишки форумного редактора. Я не говорил что функционал нужно перенимать полностью. Вы видите только минусы, а плюсов не замечаете.

Comment: Что такое "родная" подсветка? вы в блоке кода всегда можете поставить хинт  для подсветки, например `<!-- language: lang-js -->` из числе тех, которые в принципе подерживаются: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work

Comment: @Nofate, давайте на чистоту. 90% пользователей не будут отдельно оборачивать код в теги <!-- language: lang-js -->, гораздо проще и удобнее выделить блок кода и указать к какому ЯП он относится.

Comment: @Nofate, добавил примеры подсветки синтаксиса в вопрос.

Comment: @z668, у меня в IDEA "родная" подсветка Java другая, что делать будем? )

Comment: @Nofate, я так понимаю, речь о том, что для разных языков нужна разная подсветка, хотя бы потому, что набор ключевых слов везде разный, и т.д.

Comment: @klopp если посмотреть на html, парсер грамотно выделяет keywords для разных языков. Вопрос только в цветах и начертаниях. Но это вкусовщина, которую каждый может юзерскриптами себе настроить.

Comment: Ну вот: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/426485/ где выделение? Цифры и строки - мелочь. Даже комментарии не видит. GeShi (с явным указанием языка) покрасивше будет :)

Comment: @klopp, asm не входит в поддерживаемые языки просто. см. мою ссылку выше. При этом ясно говорится, что по вопросу добавления поддержки языков обращаться к авторам  *Google Code Prettify*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Из всего многообразия предложений мне кажется разумным требованием и недостающей фичей явное указание языка для подсветки. Возможно, отдельным выезжающим тулбаром. Пока этого нету в основной функциональности, может, кто-то напишет userscript?

Без выравнивания, мне кажется, можно обойтись. Табличное форматирование слишком сложно, хотя в принципе оно вполне вписывается в markdown.

> Спойлеры есть!

Comment: Слава Селестии, информация про спойлеры скрыта где-то в дебрях документации, которую никто не читает! Этот ужас её и анимирован!

Comment: IMHO, правильный спойлер должен быть ссылкой, на которую нужно кликнуть для раскрытия. В этом же варианте плохо как минимум то, что просто провести мышой над - можно запросто и случайно. Тем более что это место никак не обозначено вообще (незаметная серая полоска слева не говорит вообще ни о чём, даже если её увидеть и не посчитать пустое место обычным отступом)

Comment: @klopp: Угу, но это уже вопрос к _подробностям имплементации_ фичи, а не к её _наличию_.

Answer (score 7):

Зачем вам для того, чтобы задать вопрос целый Word? В Markdown из существенного не хватает только таблиц. А вся эта "игра со шрифтами" совершенно ни к чему.

Сами посудите:

- [-] выбор гарнитуры и цвета текста не имеет особого смысла; кому нужен цирк как в старых web-чатах?
- [+] размер заголовков уже задается, три уровня - должно хватать
- [-] выравнивание? вряд ли
- [+] списки нумерованные и нет - есть
- [+] *курсив*, **полужирный** и ***оба вместе*** - есть
- [+] [гиперссылки](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/406/) есть
- [+] имеется даже субскрипт и суперскрипт: A<sub>1</sub> и B<sup>2</sup>
- [+] подсветка кода как `inline` так и

  ```
   отдельным_блоком();
  ```
- [+] картинки есть
- [-] смайликов нет и прекрасно
- [+] хоткеи <kbd>тоже</kbd>+<kbd>есть</kbd>
- [+] и цитаты

  > куда же без них
- [+] чистый HTML также [частично поддерживается](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites)
- [-] таблиц, как я упомянул, нет, но SO уже много лет как-то справляется

Главная проблема вашего предложения: движок StackOverflow для текста вопросов и ответов использует разметку Markdown, если разметка чего-то не предусматривает, этого скорее всего никогда уже не будет.

---

Чего именно вам не хватает?

Comment: Мне не хватает: 1) Выравнивания. 2) "Родной" подсветки синтаксиса топовых языков. 3) Табличного форматирования. 4) Тега "Спойлер".

Comment: Не хватает подчёркивания, тега `<u></u>`, [у которого нет аналога](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3034334/5951529) в Markdown. Спасибо.

Answer (score 5):

Выровненный скрытыми юникодпробелами вращающийся смайлик внутри таблицы под спойлером. Черный день для @Discord наступил:

> <kbd>[image: Спойлер]</kbd>

Comment: в песочнице на META.SE и не такое есть )

Comment: @Nofate Теперь я круче этих ребят, мой растровый смайлик внезапно тоже крутится.

Comment: @igumnov: С каждым разом смайлик всё лучше и лучше!

Comment: @VladD почему то в [Xроме не скалируется нормально. В FireFox работает все.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30488478/why-this-svg-simultaneous-animatetransform-rotating-scaling-and-disappearing-do)

Answer (score 2):

1. Выравнивание *не нужно*. Бесполезная декорация.
2. Ручная подсветка *не нужна*. Движок правильно подсвечивает в 99% случаев, основываясь на метках. Пугать пользователей костылями `<!-- language: lang-foo-language -->` и `<!-- language-all: lang-foo-language -->` считаю лишним.
3. Спойлер *не нужен*. Ненавижу форумы со спойлерами (и упоротых пользователей, которые любят скрывать текст по желанию левой пятки) и всегда перекрываю стили в User CSS. Одно из двух: или текст в вопросе важен, или его следует удалить. Третьего не дано.
4. Смайлики, цвета, отступы и прочий хлам *не нужны* тем более. Добавить нечего, это должно быть очевидно.
5. Таблицы спорны. Учитывая, как мало места по ширине отводится на вопрос, содержательные таблицы невозможны. А значит, таблицы *не нужны*.

Comment: Так спойлеры есть >!SPIKEDIES

Comment: @Athari, думаете смена ника вам поможет?) От перемены мест слагаемых сумма то - не меняется.

Comment: @igumnov, кнопок нет. А перекапывать документацию, которая в добавок на английском, крайне нужное занятие. Сделать кнопку "Спойлер" в расширенном редакторе - да и все тут.

Comment: @z668 Как мне должна помочь смена ника на имя духа хаоса и раздора? Лучше скажите, на кой фиг вам сдались эти выравнивания и спойлеры.

Comment: @Discord, на аватарке я вижу козла... Но не суть. Подтолкнул к данным действиям этот вопрос: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/426295/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BA-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%83-datagridview-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC/426297#426297

Comment: Козёл раздора! Звучит. Как яблоко раздора, но круче.

Comment: @Discord, каким образом прикажете портировать полноценный ответ по ссылке: http://www.cyberforum.ru/windows-forms/thread110436.html в ответ на стеке?

Comment: @z668 В чём именно проблема при переносе текста? И таки при копипасте нужно ссылаться.

Comment: @Discord, Изначально была ссылка на полноценную тему. Nicolas Chabanovsky попросил убрать линк, выбрать ответ из множества. Вы видели ту тему на форуме? Там 3 полноценных поста с ответом, попробуйте сами их портировать в ответ сохраняя форматирование. И так же скажите сколько времени это у вас займет.

Comment: @z668 На аватарке животное, состоящее из частей дракона, лошади, летучей мыши, оленя, козла, змеи, орла, льва и ящерицы. Если вы видите только козла, то наведите мышку на аватар, и раскроется плашка с более детальной картинкой. Если вам и в таком масштабе видится только козёл, то вам к Фрейду.

Comment: @Discord, отмазались, нечего сказать) "Я не козел, я кусок козла"))) Уж не обессудьте. Повеселило.

Comment: @z668 Не вижу требования Николаса удалить ссылку. Вижу требование добавить в ответ-ссылку что-то содержательное. Тащить в ответ все варианты — лишнее. В вашем случае оптимальнее всего было бы выбрать один подходящий вариант и предоставить ссылку на остальные. Ссылка как *дополнение* к полноценному ответу — это нормально.

Comment: @Discord http://i6.5cm.ru/i/Xexs.png

Comment: @z668 Это переводится так: "В случае, если ссылка умрёт, ответ не должен стать бесполезным". Если ресурса по вашей ссылке не станет, а в вашем ответе только ссылка — он стал бесполезным. Если ресурс умер, а в ответе что-то содержательное — ответ стал менее полезным, но всё ещё остался полезным. Обратите внимание, что здесь нет ни слова про удаление ссылки из текста вопроса — речь про умирание ресурса по ссылке и полезность ответа в этом случае.

Comment: @Discord, без ссылки ответ так и так будет бесполезен. Т.к. не будет охватывать все предложенные способы решения. Дилемма.

Comment: @z668 Ваш ответ будет решать проблему автора. Эрго, он полезен. Что он не будет решать её всеми возможными способами — это второстепенно, это вопрос качества, а не достижения результата.

Comment: @z668 Вообще, тащить *весь текст* не надо. Это может быть запрещено лицензией форума и авторскими парвами. На этом сайте принято соблюдать закон. Строго говоря, может быть запрещено копировать и небольшой кусок (зависит от прав и лицензии на контент), но для небольшого куска кода пофиг. Поэтому проблема "как переформатировать мегабайт текста", вообще говоря, не очень-то должна возникать.

Comment: @Discord, программирование - это одно глобальное копирование.

Comment: @z668 За подобную философию компании попадают на сотни миллионов убитых енотов.

Comment: @Discord, глупо подавать в суд на программиста - который в своем проекте использовал готовые метода из дотнета. Методы везде одни и теже. А те кто ворует код, как правило переделывают его до неузнаваемости. Ну да ладно, это тема совсем другого вопроса.

Comment: Кстати, ответы на киберфоруме в основном ужасны. Они говорят о синтаксической возможности, но не о семантике, о том, как и когда надо делать, как _правильно_. Пример: _Чтобы отобразить вторую форму, надо создать экземпляр этого класса (Form2), например в обработчике события главной_.

Comment: @VladD, они рассчитаны на новичков в программировании. Новичок не будет заморачиваться семантикой, ему нужно сделать. А как это будет - ему без разницы. Понимание приходит с опытом, я думаю многие через это проходили.

Comment: @z668: Мне кажется, новичков надо железной рукой тащить в сторону правильного мышления. Иначе из них вырастет, хм... то, что вырастает в >50% случаев.

Comment: @VladD, я вот все думаю. Не возобновить ли раздел "Исследования" (или сделать аналогичный) хешкода? Туда помещать статьи, например у вас была хорошая статья про паттерн Поставщик\Потребитель. Куда её подевали - непонятно.

Comment: @z668, вряд ли удастся. Это довольно крупная фича, затрагивающая движок. Предлагается для подобных вещей использовать вики-вопросы и вики-ответы.

Comment: @z668: Я где-то сохранил исследование насчёт producer-consumer, надо будет восстановить.

Comment: @VladD, с удовольствием почитал бы еще другие ваши статьи (да и не я один). У вас есть блог или что-то, где можно почитать ваши материалы? Если нет - не думали завести?

Comment: @z668: Блога нет, надо бы завести, конечно. Всё в основном на ХК :)

Comment: @VladD, Незнаю что такое ХК, но как заведете блог, хотябы в профиле ссылку укажите на него.

Comment: @z668: ХэшКод же.

Comment: @VladD, да уж, не понял сразу))) Все  SO да SO)))