# Оформление текста в StackOverlow

Tags: поддержка, предложение, статус-отклонено, форматирование, markdown

Пожалуйста, сделать проще оформление ответов и комментариев.

Почему отступ на сайте происходит только в том случае если перед текстом поставить "2 пробела". Ведь на других сайта допустим на CyberForum. Там ты пишешь как в блокноте. Нажал Enter значит оступ. нажал пробел значит пробел.

И в конце то концов ну пожалуйста, добавьте Спойлер. Код трудно писать. Вставляешь код исходника, а он не отображается приходиться каждую строчку отдельно оформлять, реально задолбало уже. Возмите пример с CyberForum.

Если вы думаете что мой вопрос этот бесполезный, то создайте опросник и вы увидите что люди на 80% согласяться со мной. Потому что мы живем в 21 веке. А сайт у вас будто из 19 века.

Если что я говорю не про Мету, а про обычный ru.stackoverflow.com

P.S Короче ясно бесполезно что - то писать про улучшения. Ибо Стереотипы данных Админов и Модераторов полностью схожи с Автором сайта.

Comment: Зачем создавать ещё один опросник? Вы уже создали вопрос. Люди выразят своё мнение голосами к нему. Мета для этого и существует.

Comment: Отношение сообщества к этому предложению вполне выражается голосами по этому вопросу. В данный момент ноль за, шесть против. Это приблизительно 100% против.

Comment: А как вы предлагаете форматировать код? Сейчас код форматируется моноширинным шрифтом и с подсветкой, сайт отличает код от не-кода тем, что код отбит четырьмя пробелами слева. В случае, когда такого нет, как сайт будет знать, где код, а где текст? Или вы предлагаете избавится от раскраски кода?

Comment: @VladD настоящий программист раскрашивает код в уме)

Comment: @NickVolynkin: ... а также компилирует и выполняет!

Comment: @VladD ...распределённо и многопоточно. :)

Comment: @NickVolynkin распределённо? Надмозг же, вроде, ещё не сконструировали? .-.

Comment: `Стереотипы данных Админов и Модераторов полностью схожи с Автором сайта` — автор сайта не один человек, а *компания*, обслуживающая заявки со *всех* сайтов сети StackExchange (а их [162 штуки](https://stackexchange.com/sites#questionsperday), и за каждым из них стоит немалых размеров сообщество). **Количество сыпающихся на них заявок можете представить себе сами.** Так что представитель сообщества (*Nicolas Chabanovsky*) вынужден фильтровать предложения по улучшениям. А модераторы тут не при чём — компания с ними не работает.

Answer (score 11):

Markdown — язык разметки, разработанный специально для написания технической документации. Он должен был быть понятным и читаемым в «сыром» виде и компилироваться в красивый html, pdf и тому подобное. Эта задача вполне реализована.

## Переносы строк

Есть несколько способов сделать перенос строки:

```
первая строка<space><space><newline>
вторая строка:
```

первая строка
вторая строка

```
первая строка<newline>
<newline>
вторая строка
```

первая строка

вторая строка

Поддерживается также и HTML:

```
первая строка<br>вторая строка
```

первая строка
вторая строка

Ещё всегда переносится строка после заголовка и после блока кода

```
### Заголовок 3 уровня
текст

    код
текст
```

#### Заголовок 3 уровня

текст

```
код
```

текст

## Спойлеры

Обсуждались не раз ([1](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2666/181472), [2](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/406/181472)), и сообщество приходило к выводу, что они не нужны. Если у вас так много кода, что нужен спойлер — вопрос плохой. Нужно уменьшать количество кода и предоставить минимальный пример, воспроизводящий проблему.

[Grundy подсказывает](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3145/%D0%9E%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2-stackoverlow#comment10029_3147), что спойлеры доступны в сниппетах. Поскольку там HTML+CSS+JS, то даже минимальный пример бывает достаточно большим.

## Другие сайты и разметки

> Возмите пример с CyberForum

Сожалею, но я не знаком с этим сайтом. И с [BBCode](http://php.net/manual/en/book.bbcode.php), стандартным языком форумной разметки тоже почти не работал. Для меня он остался где-то на рубеже тысячелетий, когда компьютер для меня был исключительно средством развлечения и общения.

Но [intro94 очень подробно объяснил](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3146/181472), почему выбран именно Markdown: он удобен, широко распространён и отлично решает задачу написания технических текстов, а для удобства изучения и использования есть кнопки редактора и горячие клавиши.

Comment: под спойлеры кстати сниппеты убираются, как workaround

Comment: @Grundy спасибо, добавил.

Answer (score 10):

Если вы страдаете от использования Markdown, то вы используте его неправильно.

Перенос с помощью двух пробелов в конце — это костыль. Он практически никогда не должен использоваться. Почти во всех случаях следует использовать **разрыв на параграфы, который задаётся в тексте двойным переносом строк**. Текст в вебе принято форматировать параграфами без красной строки, но с разрывом между параграфами (обычно 0.5–1 высоты строки).

**Код не надо выравнивать построчно**. На панели инструментов есть кнопочка для добавления отступа к выделенному тексту, ей соответствует сочетание <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>. Некоторые проблемы могут возникать разве что при форматировании коде внутри списков.

**Спойлеры не нужны**. Во-первых, блоки кода ограничены по высоте, поэтому отчасти уже служат спойлерами. Во-вторых, если у вас много кода, то, скорее всего, вы не следуете MCVE. В-третьих, спойлеры замедляют чтение вопроса, что критично для сайтов с большим трафиком.

BB-код уходит в прошлое, смиритесь. Его скобки слишком неудобно набирать на клавиатуре, и он слишком многословен. Markdown — "возрождение" текстового форматирования, которое было распространено до появления всяких веб-форумов. Он может казаться неестественным только для тех, кто оказался в Интернете в узком промежутке времени, когда процветали всякие PHPBB. BB-код — это костыль, оставшийся со времён, когда HTML валидировать ещё нормально не научились.

Answer (score 9):

На сайте используется редактор Markdown. Если вы не умеете им пользоваться, это не значит, что он плохой. Лично я считаю его лучшим. И он стал популярен именно в 21 веке! А вот упомянутый вами КиберФорум устарел в плане дизайна и в плане морально устаревшего редактора BB-кодов. И 80% пользователей стека, я думаю, согласятся, что Markdown здесь очень даже кстати. Это редактор для `programmer == true;` :)

Редактор Markdown достаточно популярен среди программистов. Самые известные сообщества, использующие его: Habrahabr, сообщества сети StackExchange. Он активно используется на хостингах репозиториев Git. Например GitHub, GitLab и BitBucket. Используется для разметки файлов `README.md`, обычно находящихся в репозиториях.

Что мешает вам вставить (или написать) свой код по-человечески, без пробелов, выделить весь, и нажать кнопку "*пример кода*" вверху редактора (или нажать сочетание клавиш <kbd>Ctrl+K</kbd>? А ещё можно прямо перед вашим кодом и после него поставить три косых кавычки (не знаю, как они правильно называются). Вот такие вот ```. :)

P.S.: И кстати. Не два пробела, а два переноса строки.

Comment: Я почему на кибере не сижу, потому что там мало людей по моей специализации. Ибо весь гугл ответы на вопросы выдает через сайт StackOverlow. Именно по этой причине я тут сижу. А не потому что дизайн старый. Если честно у вас тоже дизайн недавно более менее нормальный стал.

А может быть лучше вы вообще уберете тогда редактор. Будем как в 19 веке через HTML писать. Чего тут трудного)), Ведь HTML все знают.

Такое ощущение что создатель сайта тупо застрял в каком то веке и не хочет уходить оттуда по личным причинам.

И смайлики тоже будем сами писать ;D. Я прямо ICQ вспоминаю года 
199x.

Comment: Такое ощущение, что вы вообще не прочитали мой ответ. Где вы видите устаревший редактор? Да, язык Markdown был впервые опубликован в 2004 году. Но он не устаревший. Он активно используется и среди программистов, и есть очень много улучшений и дополнений. Взять, хотя бы, многочисленные `README.md`. Если вам он не нравится, это не повод называть его устаревшим. P.S.: вы в соседней теме ругались насчёт минусов, а сами горазды их ставить куда ни попадя. :)

Comment: А вы чем лучше, вы же мне тоже поставили). Был бы коммент я бы описал причину.

А ведь из - за этих минусов Вопросы и теряют свою актуальность. Люди не экстрасенсы они не могут понять в чем причина минусов.

Даже вот эти комменты читаются трудно. Потому что все в сплошную. Разве нельзя абзацы и отсутпы добавить. Зачем на клавиатуре мне Enter ;D. Он на этом сайте бесполезный. Что нажму что не нажму все равно все в всплошную будет))

Comment: @xTIGRx я вам минус не ставил. Вот пруф: [скриншот](http://i.imgur.com/XINdhnF.png). :)

Comment: Вот видишь. А я подумал что это ты. Вот оттуда и идет вся эта не стыковка. Да ясно короче. Все бесполезно. Meta сайт бесполезности.На других сайтах по улучшению можно опросники создавать хотя бы.

Или вот Петиция тоже ведь нормальная вещь. Собрал голоса и закон на рассмотрении.

А тут не понятно что. Хочешь чтобы как лучше было. А получается как хуже.

Comment: @xTIGRx а минусы не созданы для того, чтобы минусить *потому что он мне минус поставил*. Ответ плохой - минус. Ответ хороший - даже если автор меня обидел, то всё равно плюс. Вам, простите, пофиг на ответ - проходим мимо. :)

Comment: Читайте PS в вопросе моем выше. Говорить бесполезно

Comment: @xTIGRx вы не правы. Убирать MD это не улучшение, а большое ухудшение. А улучшения администрацией принимаются. :)

Comment: Что касается разделения отношения к человеку и к сообщениям: подтверждаю, на Мете немало примеров, когда участник А отдал много голосов как за так и против сообщения участника Б. Гораздо реже бывает "строго против".

Answer (score 6):

Один из основных принципов Markdown — выглядеть понятно даже в исходном виде, "прямым текстом", даже в примитивных редакторах. А после пропускания через рендереры, вроде преобразователя в HTML, не терять смысл.

Проще всего о нём думать, как о языке, на котором пишутся комментарии в коде. Один из. Простенький, без метаданных. Несмотря на это, есть целый ряд генераторов документации, использующий их.

А учитывая аудиторию StackOverflow... это основное назначение языка как нельзя кстати.

---

Код обычно ограничен по ширине. Комментарии в коде, очевидно, тоже. В консервативных кругах лимит 79-80 символов, где-то 120. Поэтому чтобы бить текст на логические блоки-абзацы, использовать один перенос уже нельзя. Используют два. Заодно получают чёткое визуальное отделение пустой строкой.

`<br>`, как и два пробела в конце строки ради явного переноса, часто используют неаккуратно, слепляя текст в сплошную простыню без отдельных логических блоков. Реальная необходимость для таких переносов есть разве что **в стихах** (*на SO, стихи, ага*), в остальных случаях абзацы куда уместнее. Так что подобное "усложнение" неявно работает на качество оформления. Конечно, при условии, что автор посматривает в превьюшку. Если не посматривает, то он либо о ней не знает (намекните), либо его вопрос всё равно придётся редактировать кому-то другому, кто посматривает.

А если надо отформатировать большой объём, не делайте это руками. Программист вы или нет? Используйте кнопки редактора здесь или свой любимый редактор для кода.

Мне, к примеру, примеры кодом проще написать в своём любимом редакторе, а затем сделать <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd>, <kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>Tab</kbd> (у меня отступы по 2 пробела), <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd> (хвост первого отступа), <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> и вставить в ответ. А поскольку мой редактор лучше приспособлен для редактирования кода, чем местный, примеры получаются даже быстрее, чем если бы я писал их здесь.

---

Отсутствие большого количества средств оформления, вроде спойлеров, тоже полезно из-за формата сообщества: только вопросы и ответы, никаких "красочных публикаций" и сильно структурированной спискоты (и редкость исключений в этом только подтверждает правило).

Что не относится к ответу напрямую, но может быть интересно (основной юзкейс *сворачиваемого* спойлера), лучше приложить ссылкой. Что относится к вопросу напрямую, но слишком большое для постоянной прокрутки, лучше не вставлять в вопрос вообще и убрать несущественное, потому что авторы ответов могут плюнуть, решить не читать простыни и просто идти дальше, оставляя автора вопроса без ответа, в чём он сам же в первую очередь не заинтересован.

...строго говоря, спойлеры тут есть, но в более "традиционном" для этого слова смысле: блоки, содержимое которых "условно секретно" (как спойлеры сюжета, которые интереснее увидеть самому) и чтобы прочитать их, пользователь должен совершить какое-то явное действие. Но они намеренно лишены "сворачивания", чтобы избежать "использования не по назначению", см. выше.

> Зацените — этот текст невидим, пока его не пощупают.

```
>! Зацените &mdash; этот текст невидим, пока его не пощупают.
```

Answer (score 0):

Ничего сложного в `markdown` нет. `markdown` - многофункциональная разметка, но в то же время и простая. И вам не обязательно использовать все её возможности. В конце-концов мы - сайт программистов, поэтому выучить пару несложных трюков думаю, любому из нас под силу.

В принципе, можно обойтись лишь этим:

```
текст

    код

>Цитата

`Понятие` *Курсив* **Жирный** ***жирный и курсив***

[Описание ссылки](ссылка)

![Описание картинки](ссылка на картинку)
```

текст

```
код
```

> Цитата

`Понятие` *Курсив* **Жирный** ***жирный и курсив***

[Описание ссылки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

[image: Описание картинки]

Но для тех, кто хочет, чтобы его вопросы/ответы были ещё красивей, есть такое:

```
>!Спойлер (то, чего вы так желали)

1. Первое
2. Второе 

+ Элемент маркированного списка 1
+ Элемент маркированного списка 2

# Большой заголовок

## Средний заголовок

### Маленький заголовок

[tag:ссылка-на-метку]
```

> Спойлер (то, чего вы так желали)

1. Первое
2. Второе

- Элемент маркированного списка 1
- Элемент маркированного списка 2

## Большой заголовок

### Средний заголовок

#### Маленький заголовок

[ссылка-на-метку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%83)